# Reading File in PHP: File Path Issues

Tags: php, filepath

Please can someone tell me what I've done wrong here? I have a simple txt file and a php file in the same folder, but the php file meant to read and output the content of txt file cannot do it. I guess it's file path issue please help.

```
<?php
    //open target file
    $fp = fopen("sample_file.txt", 'r');
    echo fread($fp, filesize($fp));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

> Error: [17-Dec-2017 05:28:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread(): Length
>   parameter must be greater than 0 in
>   /home/chuzymat/public_html/file_reader/read_sample.php on line 6

Comment: To read the contents of a file, try [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
echo file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/sample_file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this Code

```
 $fp = fopen("sample_file.txt", 'r');
 echo fread($fp,filesize("sample_file.txt"));
 fclose($fp);
```